# Connecting Multidimensional Cube to PowerView

Tags: ssas, excel-2013, powerview, sql-server-2012-datatools, sql-data-tools

i am new to SSAS . we can connect tabular model in SSAS to powerview .
Can we connect Multidimensional Cube(Datatools) also to  Powerview  without sharepoint

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. Currently you need to host your PowerView in SharePoint in order to be able to connect to a multidimensional cube. 
However, when Excel 2016 is released you will be able to connect PowerView in Excel to multidimensional cubes. See the PowerView over an OLAP Connection section in this article: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Whats-new-in-Office-2016-Preview-4841f061-d019-45cc-af74-3e89c8cff1c4

Comment: That link does not have any information regarding Power View, OLAP, or multidimensional SSAS cubes.